# Speed up dataframe creation from a dictionary that is updated in advance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

The following code creates a `dataframe` based on a dictionary that is updated in advance:

```py
import pandas as pd

clothes = {'items': [{'id': '912SAFD', 'key': 3, 'list_index': [0]},
                     {'id': '812SAFD', 'key': 4, 'list_index': [0, 1]},
                     {'id': '712SAFD', 'key': 5, 'list_index': [2]}]}

designs = [{'designs': [{'color_id': 609090, 'value': 'b', 'spare': ''}, {'color_id': 609094, 'value': 'e', 'spare': ''}]}, 
           {'designs': [{'color_id': 609091, 'value': 'c', 'spare': ''}]}, 
           {'designs': [{'color_id': 609092, 'value': 'd', 'spare': 'fr'}]}]


for item in clothes['items']:
    if 'list_index' in item:
      for i in item['list_index']:
        for d in designs[i]['designs']:
          item[d['color_id']] = d['value']
          if d['spare']:
              item[str(d['color_id']) + '-spare'] = d['spare']

df = pd.DataFrame(clothes['items'])
```

```
        id  key list_index 609090 609094 609091 609092 609092-spare
0  912SAFD    3        [0]      b      e    NaN    NaN          NaN
1  812SAFD    4     [0, 1]      b      e      c    NaN          NaN
2  712SAFD    5        [2]    NaN    NaN    NaN      d           fr
```

Is it possible to speed up this code, perhaps by removing some loops or using `pandas` operations?

Comment: is the dictionary provided in the same format or you can have it in other format as well

Comment: always the same format

Comment: Any idea @gilfOyle?

Comment: if at its this way {'id': ['912SAFD','dsds','ds'], 'key':[ 3,2,3], 'list_index': [[0],[2,3],[2,4]]}    you can make it simple but in its current form its really hard to do.